# Liferay 7.2 render url of a portlet with instance

Tags: liferay, portlet

I have Liferay 7.2.

Jsp file for the view of a custom portlet.

I'm trying to generate a url from a custom portlet to link the **document media** portlet (com_liferay_document_library_web_portlet_DLPortlet).

I try

```
<liferay-portlet:actionURL name="newMyNew"  portletName="com_liferay_document_library_web_portlet_DLPortlet" var="prueba2"></liferay-portlet:actionURL>
```

output:

```
http://localhost:8080/web/guest/home?p_p_id=com_liferay_document_library_web_portlet_DLPortlet&p_p_lifecycle=1&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&_com_liferay_document_library_web_portlet_DLPortlet_javax.portlet.action=newMyNew&p_auth=1IDKtzvU
```

But i need the instance ID of the **Document Media** portlet (com_liferay_document_library_web_portlet_DLPortlet) because i need that it receive the variables like folderId

i need this output:

```
http://localhost:8080/web/guest/home/-/document_library/jFOlAlmeJgMl/view/34527?_com_liferay_document_library_web_portlet_DLPortlet_INSTANCE_jFOlAlmeJgMl_redirect=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fweb%2Fguest%2Fhome%3Fp_p_id%3Dcom_liferay_document_library_web_portlet_DLPortlet_INSTANCE_jFOlAlmeJgMl%26p_p_lifecycle%3D0%26p_p_state%3Dnormal%26p_p_mode%3Dview
```

How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to get the instance id of portlet

```
List<Portlet> portletListDUE = layoutTypePortlet.getAllPortlets();  
String portletInstanceId = "";
for(Portlet portletIn : portletListDUE) {
    
            String portletNameOfInstance = portletIn.getPortletName();
            if(portletNameOfInstance.equals("com_liferay_document_library_web_portlet_DLPortlet")) 
            {
                portletInstanceId = portletIn.getInstanceId();
            }
    }
```